# Qml Repeater with ids

Tags: qt, qml

If wrote the following code:

```
Repeater { model: 10; 
delegate: Rectangle { width: 200; height:           
20; color: "white";}}
```

How can I give all the 10 rectangles a different id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not assign a different id, also the id has a scope whose limit is the delegate, if you want to access an item you must use the [`itemAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method) method passing the index:

```
Repeater { 
    id: repeater
    model: 10; 
    delegate: Rectangle { 
        width: 200; 
        height: 20; 
        color: "white";
    }
}

// ...

var item = repeater.itemAt(2)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. If i create a Textinput inside the Rectangle; how can i access the text from the textinput?

Comment: @JohnSmith you can give the text an id like `textInput` and access it like `repeater.itemAt(2).textInput`

Comment: @MorJ This doesn't work. I will post the Code in an answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith it seems i was wrong, sorry for misleading you. Well, at least you can do like this: `repeater.itemAt(2).children[0]` to access the textInput. This is ugly, but it works. I suggest you use the answer from Adrien Leravat or suggest another thing you want to accomplish that his code doesn't.

Comment: The error message if the same as in my answer. Only the property is now child. I think the itemat() method doesn't wok, because `the property of NULL`

Comment: And in the code from Adrien nowhere he mentioned the TextInput.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want to do you can either

### A. Access the item from its index

You can access elements their index, using the `itemAt` method of the repeater, as indicated by @eyllanesc. Be careful, as delegates may not be  instantiated yet.

```
    Repeater { 
        id: repeater
        model: 5

        Component.onCompleted: {
            if (repeater.count > 0) {
                var firstRect = repeater.itemAt(0)
                // do something
            }
        }

        Rectangle { /*...*/ }
   }
```

### B. Use `itemAdded` signal

You can connect to the [`itemAdded`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAdded-signal) signal of the `Repeater`. This signal is triggered whenever an item is added (of course) and will provide the item `index` and `item`.

```
    Repeater { 
        id: repeater
        model: 5

        property Item firstRect

        onItemAdded: {
            // `index` and `item` come from the signal
            if (index == 0) {
                firstRect = item
                // Or do something with item
            }
        }

        Rectangle { /*...*/ }
    }
```

### C. Delegate assign itself to a property

You can have rectangles assign themselves to a property declared in one of their parents. This is usually not preferred, as your delegate now depends on that named property to be there, but it might be useful.

```
    Repeater { 
        id: repeater
        model: 5

        // That property can be anywhere
        property Item firstRect

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 50; height: 50;
            Component.onCompleted: { 
                // Index is automatically populated by the Repeater
                if (index == 0)                
                    repeater.firstRect = rect
            }
        }
    }
```

Most of the time, you want to avoid any dependency from delegates to parents, so solutions A and B are preferred. But it always depends!