# Binding text from a TextField that belongs to a Repeater

Tags: qt, qml

My main.qml:

```
Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "grey"

    GridLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns : 2
        rows    : 2

        Repeater
        {
            id: rectRepeater
            model: 3
            TextField
            {
                text: "hi"
            }

        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: r1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 200
        y: 200
        border.color: "red"
        Text
        {
            id: t1
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        t1.text= rectRepeater.itemAt(0).text
    }
}
```

The Text in the rectangle `r1` displays the text at the start, but if I enter new text to the TextField, the rectangle will not be updated. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant and maintainable solution is to implement a model that reflects the changes, and then make a binding of the first element with the text that shows Text:

```
Window{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "grey"
    ListModel{
        id: mymodel
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
            mymodel.append({"text" : "hi"})
        }
    }
    GridLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns : 2
        rows    : 2
        Repeater{
            model: mymodel
            TextField{
                id: tf
                onTextChanged: model.text = tf.text
                Component.onCompleted: tf.text= model.text
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id: r1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 200
        y: 200
        border.color: "red"
        Text {
            id: t1
            text: mymodel.count > 1 ? mymodel.get(0).text : ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but later I have 81 entries, so the Modellist would be very long

Comment: @JohnSmith I was just thinking about the disadvantages with my solution, look at my updated solution :-)

Comment: Okay this is better, but what is the advantage over the accepted solution?

Comment: @JohnSmith 1. Qt recommends not doing a direct binding(`text: mymodel.count > 1 ? mymodel.get(0).text : ""`) since it saves resources that use Qt.binding (`t1.text = Qt.binding(function() { return rectRepeater.itemAt(0).text })`) which may fail for certain levels since Qt is currently trying to fix it.

Comment: @JohnSmith [cont.] 2)  Another advantage is that you can undo the views (TextEdit & Text) since the information is centered on the model, let's say you want to change the TextEdit to another Item that does not have the "text" property but another "value" like the spinboxes, with my solution only change the code of the SpinBox without modifying another code, however with the above you have to modify both.

Comment: Ok, but does that not take much more ram through the list?

Comment: And which variant is faster?

Comment: @JohnSmith How many bytes occupies more data? In an application that will be maintainable, it is usually given a light layer so that maintenance is simple and it costs a few bytes, but in exchange it helps us. If your mentality is to save you bytes instead of simplifying the process then you should not use Qt but the native code of each OS or do you think that the layer added for Qt is multiplatform has no cost ?, in C ++ the minimization is a bad practice .

Comment: @JohnSmith *And which variant is faster?*, Because it would be difficult to know since your example does not cover all the possibilities, on average both are fast, but for your "simple application" one would be faster for microseconds, and that is called mini- optimization that in practical questions does not give any advantage,  it is like saying that an algorithm of compression of images is faster than another because it takes one byte less.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try both variants and then choose.

Comment: @JohnSmith Exactly, in the end you decide which method is the best for you. The experience will tell you what is the best option, in my case I prefer to use the models that give me flexibility, at the beginning I wanted to optimize everything, maybe for small applications it serves but for large applications it is impossible.

Comment: I think i will use your method, but i will first tried both out. If I choose your method, i will change the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is to create a binding between the two.

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    t1.text = Qt.binding(function() { return rectRepeater.itemAt(0).text })
}
```

That being said, we would need to know exactly what you are trying to do, because creating bindings manually is an anti-pattern when not required. It is much better to bind directly, or to use signals.

Do you need the first elements, and the repeater, or is this just an test for you? What is your UI and what are you trying to achieve? This is some context worth giving for a proper answer.

One possible simpler solution

```
Repeater
{
    id: rectRepeater
    model: 3
    TextField
    {
        text: "hi"
        // See also `onEditingFinished` and `onValidated`
        onTextChanged: {
            if (index == 0)
                t1.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

For more details about the property thing, look at my answers from your other question: [Qml Repeater with ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308872/qml-repeater-with-ids/55309180#55309180)